Upgrading the PSU in an Acer Aspire XC-1780
I have an Acer Aspire XC-1780 and I want to install a graphics card. I'm aware of some constraints - basically that it has a 180W power supply and the case is really small.
So, first I'm pretty sure I need to upgrade the PSU. My understanding is that the best I can do with this machine is a 300W supply (either DC.3001B.00A or DC.30018.00C) - although to my eyes they are virtually identical (is there a difference?) - there are more powerful PSUs out there, but they won't fit? Is this correct?

I have googled and looked at forums.  They are equivalent.  The specs are the same.
Blurb from Ebay

Description: New Acer 300 watt computer power supply. 
Compatible Part #'s: DC.30018.00C, DC.30018.00D, DC.3001B.00A, FSP300-10TAA 
Compatible Models: Acer Aspire XC-875, XC-895, XC-1660G Acer Aspire TC-875, TC-1660.

They may have minor differences or they were made in different factories.
